# Java 1.6.0_26 on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: java, macos, osx-lion, knime

A third party application I'm using (Knime) hangs when using Java for Mac 1.6.0_29 (Java for OS X Lion Update 1). In the user forums of that app, it is recommended to use version 1.6.0_26.

Sadly, I got a fresh install, so there are no previous Java versions installed in my computer to downgrade to.

I've been looking for a while and still cannot find out how to install a previous version of Java for Mac OS X Lion.

Any ideas?

Comment: The latest should be 1.6.0_31. I think they fixed the issue in that, so you can try upgrading not down? You can find old Java builds on [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) but I don't see Mac though.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too... Then I read http://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-users/java-160-29-causes-knime-to-crash#comment-25662: "`...1.6.0_31 pending release from Apple does not fix this issue...`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:
 - Register for a (free) Developer account at Apple: http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/
 - Go to Downloads: http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/downloads
 - Click **Developer Tools** on the right-hand side
 - Scroll down until you see **Java for Mac OS X 10.7 Developer Package** - this should include 1.6.0_26.

As an alternative, you can download the 10.6 Java Update 5 from the same page and use these instructions to replace your current installation: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100123192950640

Answer (score 1):

Too late for the original question, but, for the record, Knime has apparently fixed the error:

http://knime.org/about/news/knime-version-254-released